# Java boolean if-statement messes up

Tags: java, if-statement, calendar, hashmap, boolean

I have this if-statement that when I check with a JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (as seen in top of the code) returns false but the block is still executed. I cannot see what I should do different.
Variables:

- c = GregorianCalendar
- s = String
- h = HashMap-array - String, Date
- oldGoods1, 2, and 3 = HashMaps - String, Date

Code:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, c.after((Date) h[counter].get(s)));
if(c.after((Date) h[counter].get(s))); //this line
{
  Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
  if(today.after((Date) h[counter].get(s)))
  {
    GoodsList.removeDate(s, (Date) h[counter].get(s));
  }
  if(!oldGoods1.containsKey(s)) 
  {
    oldGoods1.put(s, (Date) h[counter].get(s));
  }
  else if(!oldGoods2.containsKey(s))
  {
    oldGoods2.put(s, (Date) h[counter].get(s));
  }
  else if(!oldGoods3.containsKey(s))
  {
    oldGoods3.put(s, (Date) h[counter].get(s));
  }
}
```

Thanks beforehand
Highace2

Comment: You have a semicolon after your if statement. The rest of your code executes as a block. A fairly common beginner error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if(c.after((Date) h[counter].get(s)));  // The `;` is the culprit. Remove it.
```

There is a semi-colon at the end of the `if statement`, which terminates the `if statement` there only, and the following block which is just a local block, is always executed regardless of what the condition evaluates to.

Comment: Oh dammit...  I've been sitting and looking for that error in 3 hours now! Anyway thanks for help.